# Stack Overflow, Avast detected infection PHP:Decode-DE [Trj]

Tags: support

I just tried to open https://stackoverflow.com/tags → *php* → *newest*, and at that point I got a warning from Avast:

> Infection: PHP:Decode-DE [Trj].

I just wanted to inform you guys and am not sure this is the right way, but better this way than not at all, I guess.

Comment: Since SO doesn't run on PHP, this is very likely a false positive caused by there being code contained in these pages.

Comment: AVAST is quite a scourge, generates entirely too many SO questions as well.  It is junk, get rid of it.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not just AVAST. ESET NOD32 Antivirus has the same thing it seems.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it's picking up on the summary of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936592/php-replace-callback-to-be-used-instead-of-php-replace-e-modifier-has-been-dep), which obviously is entirely harmless here since it's not being executed.

Comment: I mean, I hate PHP questions as much as the next guy, but who'd go to the trouble of rigging AV software anyway?

Comment: I just opened **this** page and got the warning :/

Comment: What's more worthless... PHP, or AV?  That's the question.

Answer (score 12):

Pretty sure your AV is tripping on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30936592/php-replace-callback-to-be-used-instead-of-php-replace-e-modifier-has-been-dep) whose summary is currently visible on the PHP tag page, which contains this snippet:

```
preg_replace("/.*/e","\x65\x76\x61\x6C\x28\x67\x7A\x69\x6E\x66\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x28\x62\x61\x73........HDp7YQZ+f/gI='\x29\x29\x29\x3B","");
```

Oops, did your access to Meta just fail? Well, if your AV isn't allowing you to visit developer websites which contain code snippets containing a `preg_replace(//e)`, you should probably tone down your overzealous AV software. The snippet itself it entirely harmless on the page, since it's neither being executed nor completely executable.

Comment: Ty for the information everyone, just wanted to be a good user and report a possible bug. but it seems to be nothing.

Comment: No problem. I'm just snarky since this is a perfect proof why AV software is mostly useless these days... :)